# How to Handle 3 level permisions on fields in Django REST framework

Tags: python, django, angularjs, permissions, django-rest-framework

I am building Django REST as backend and Angular JS as front end.

Now I have permissions systems very advanced as 3 level

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField()
    username = serializers.CharField(max_length=100)
    field1 = serializers.CharField(max_length=100)
    field2 = serializers.CharField(max_length=100)
    field3 = serializers.CharField(max_length=100)
    field4 = serializers.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Now want permissions on

```
User Role
view
READ / Write / Update /Delete
```

There are  10 Roles , 30 views like `/user/view1` `/user/view2` and then READ or write like

These are on field level permissions like

```
Field1 can be READ by Manager level on view 1
Field1 can be Edit by Manager level on view 2
Feild1 can be Delete by Admin on View 1
```

I am confused how can i have that sort of permission model.

Comment: How are you expecting to set up these permissions? I've got a general idea of how this could be done generically, but I have no idea how you are expecting to define the permissions.

Comment: Did you get a solution to your requirements? Am in a similar position and looking for a sane way to solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

I typically recommend different serializer classes for these cases, but that limits you to read and write permissions (kind of) and may not completely fit your needs.

You would create a serializer for each permission level. Lets say there are three permission levels: Admin, Manager, Normal user.

```
class NormalUserSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField(read_only=True, required=True)
    username = serializers.CharField(max_length=100, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        fields = ("email", "username", )

class ManagerUserSerializer(NormalUserSerializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField(read_only=False, required=True)
    username = serializers.CharField(max_length=100, read_only=False)

class AdminSerializer(ManagerUserSerializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField(read_only=False, required=False)
    username = serializers.CharField(max_length=100, read_only=False)
```

This will limit normal users to a read-only view of the fields (`read_only` is enforced by DRF). For managers, they have the ability to read and write to the fields, but they are not able to clear out the contents of the `email` field (enforced by `required`). Admins have the ability to read and write to all of the fields, as well as clear out the contents of the `email` field.

Your view would then return the correct serializer class in `get_serializer_class` based on the role of the authenticated user.

```
class UserViewSet(ModelViewSet):

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.request.user.is_superuser:
            return AdminUserSerializer

        if self.request.user.is_staff:
            return ManagerUserSerializer

        return NormalUserSerializer
```

The other option is enforcing everything in your `validate` method, and manually removing fields in the `to_native` method on the serializer. If you can live with creating a serializer for each role, it is the easiest and (arguably) the most cleanest way of implementing role-based permissions on individual fields in Django REST Framework.

Comment: The problem is if i have 10 Roles and 30 Models then i have to define 300 serializers.

Comment: @KKJOJ This answer doesn't scale well, but I feel like field-based permissions don't scale well in _any_ situation. If I think of a better, more scalable way to do this, then I'll post a separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same problem with a client. I created [django-rest-framework-roles](https://github.com/computer-lab/django-rest-framework-roles) to automatically parameterize a given DRF method (e.g: get_queryset, get_serializer_class) over the type of user. This way you don't have to repeatedly type out conditional blocks over the types of users.

I would like to extend the library to handle the more complex permissions problems you are describing. I have these same challenges, e.g: parameterizing over Role **and** HTTP verb.